# Placing Label in QGIS with EasyCustomLabeling?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

I've converted the labels for a feature class I have using the EasyCustomLabeling tool in QGIS 3.2. Other labels within the layer are not having the same problem. I'm trying to place the label in an area that has no other overlapping labels or features. However, the label will get close but not stay quite where I want it, instead snapping far either to the right or the left. Does anyone have insight into why this is happening, or what I can do to remedy it?

[image: It'll either snap to here]

[image: Or It'll snap to here]

[image: But ideally I'd like the left of the label to be right up against the river here]

Pic 1 and 2 shows the two places it loves to snap, and pic 3 is the location where I want it to be but it's phobic of.

Comment: Would you be able to temporarily turn snapping off in QGIS?

Settings > Configure Shortcuts > Snapping Options

Comment: Snapping doesn't seem to be the issue, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Sorry, still spit-balling here, but would adjusting the "digitizing" options for snapping make any difference? I'm also curious if converting the label to a graphic/annotation would work allowing static placement vs dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried zooming in closer and then placing it more carefully? It may end up closer or further away than you'd like but you should have an option that results in a vertical leader line rather than angled or elbowed ones. The "snapping" of the leader lines is part of the expression behind it which I believe looks at the azimuth of the label to the point

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue and did a bit of research. I have done many projects in QGIS and never had this occur, but for some reason a particular map was giving me troubles. It could be something regarding the projection.

Check out this youtube video. Your question will likely be answered around minute 1:45 (I think you have made it past the first four minutes, but it may be helpful to see the progression): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jBg3tTwl70

Changing the 'Label with' option to 'Decision' under the Label options seems to work. I also toyed with selecting 'Offset from Centroid' which gave the movement a bit more flexibility.